# Diagonalizablity of a substochastic matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, stochastic-processes, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, stochastic-matrices, generalized-eigenvector

Let *D+E* be  a stochastic matrix i. e., *D+E* be the matrix with each row sum *1*, where *D* and *E* are non-zero nonnegetive, irreducible matrices, *I-D* being non-singular. Can it be proved that *D+kE* is diagonalizable for *0< |k| <1*? I tried different pair of matrices *(D, E)*,  but each time it is diagonalizable, but I can't prove it generally. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If that what you write is true, then $D = D+0\cdot E$ would be diagonalizable. But what about $D = \left(\begin{matrix}0&1\\0&0\end{matrix}\right)$?

Comment: In that Case I think D is not stochastic matrix

Comment: You only required $D+E$ to be stochastic (which can be accomplished in the example with, e.g., $E = \left(\begin{matrix}0&0\\1&0\end{matrix}\right)$).

Comment: BTW, it's not surprising that you got diagonalizability in your examples because any random square matrix is diagonalizable with probability 1.

Comment: Sorry everyone! One thing I missed that the matrix D and E both are irreducible matrix and k not equal to 0